# Can I install Android app without all required app permissions?

Tags: permissions

For many apps on Google play such as Facebook I would like to install them, but I would not provide all the access they require while installing. For instance, I would not like to provide the access to Contacts. Is this possible?

I am targeting the Android versions 6 and later.

I know how to revoke the permissions later time, but installation time, Facebook prompts me with the big accept list, that at that time I cannot disable.

The `needs access to` dialog pops just after I press the install button.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an app targets Android 6 or higher, most of the permissions listed in your screenshot will have to be approved (or denied) by the user at runtime – i.e. when you're using the app. There are several permissions not falling into this category, as Google defined them as "normal" (and only "dangerous" permissions are considered worthwhile to be presented to the user). So you e.g. will never be asked for Internet access (if you denied, Google couldn't show ads).

---

OTOH one of course could argue: if you're concerned about your privacy, Facebook is the wrong place to go in general :) And of course again, if you don't trust an app, watch out for alternatives. Best at [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) where you can trust every app.

Comment: I would like to switch on "runtime permissions" model somehow. At the moment "needs access to" dialog forces me to Accept on all. I am still not sure if there is some setting where I can manage the accept.

Comment: @lzzy, btw, I am on Android 7.1 I believe if this helps.

Comment: You can't "switch that on": either the app targets Android <6 (then it's off), or the app targets Android 6+ (and its on). All up to the dev. For older apps, you can just "revoke" permissions afterwards, if your ROM allows. Again rudimentary this is possible via *Settings › Apps* (either by a global "permissions" tab, or via a "permissions" button on each app's details page).

Comment: @lzzy, I would switch that off if possible. My question was how to suppers `need access to` dialog if possible.

Comment: `All up to the dev. ` Can you clarify this. Are you saying that this depends on the device?

Comment: ``` For older apps, you can just "revoke" permissions afterwards, if your ROM allows.```  Yes. I can do that from Settings > Apps, I can confirm that. I can control the access permissions for any app, not just for some older apps.

Comment: @prosti your question didn't say you just want to suppress the *dialog* (which is a bad idea anyway; I'd rather want to have it complete again). You wrote you want to install an app without the listed permissions – and that's what my answer matches. And it's up to the dev what permissions the app requires, as well as what Android version (and thus permission model) he compiles it for. And yes, you can control *some* permissions via *Settings* but not all (e.g. no Internet).

Comment: @lzzy, the dialog we are talking about is not providing the option to accept or deny a service installation time. You must accept all in bulk. I would not say this is good or bad, but how you would install that app without suppressing this dialog? I guess I need to ask another question :)

Comment: Created https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196664/is-it-possible-to-suppres-the-bulk-access-dialog

Comment: @Izzy "Best at *<anyplace>* where you can trust every app."  Come on now, you know better than to make a blanket statement like that.  FDroid is a reputable marketplace, and lots of transparency, but there's no way anyone can guarantee any app marketplace to that degree.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser name a better place. But agreed, healthy scepticism never hurts. Though, it's still more true than "only install from Playstore because that's the {only} safe place" (whether with or without the "only"). From a privacy standpoint, Playstore is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

no that is not possible at that time because they are preset conditions in the android manifest which need to be fulfilled before downloading the app on your device

Comment: Wver heard about "runtime permissions"? If an app targets Android 6 or higher, e.g. access to the Camera, Photos/Media/Files, Contacts, Calendars etc. will have to be approved (or denied) by the user when the app runs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jainil looks like you are right but I will check for more feedback on another answer.

Comment: @prosti that's only true for Android 5 and below, as I've pointed out.